# Test factory method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Write tests to coverage 100% code is something we should attempt to achieve. But I came up with situaction where I don't know how to test method (factory method):

```
public function getDocument(){
    $document = new Document();
    $document->settings(new Settings());
    $document->filesystem(new Filesystem('e:'));
    return $document;
}
```

Purpose of that method is shortcut to create document, without everytime write 3 lines.

How to test this method?

Or maybe this is situation why we have @codeCoverageIgnoreStart block? Exactly for that reason PHPUnit provide this kind fo annotations.

---

EDIT:
The main idea behind this method is make client life easier. Nothing more, no configuration etc.(but the method will be good place to do it).

```
//I don't want bother client with Settings() and Filesystem('e:')
$document = new Document(new Settings(), new Filesystem()); //NO
$document = Files.getDocument() //much easier and shorter.

//Changing API to getDocument($var, $var) make no sense, the same thing I could have normally.
$document = new Document(new Settings(),new Filesystem('e:'));
```

Maybe I should thing about if I really should provide that method, user who want use document should know of dependences, it shouldn't be hide.

Comment: What's problem? For this method need test that document have definite settings and filesystem.

Comment: Sure, I now that. But in unit testing we shouldn't rely on dependencies, so test should pass even if Settings or Filesystem class is not defined yet.

Comment: @tne says right answer. Read about depency injection [in this article](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this method does? Returns initialized `Document` object. So all you have to verify is that the returned value is a `Document` instance and that it has `Settings` and `Filesystem` objects set. Easy if you have getters for those, otherwise you have to access the respective properties.

The test may sound very basic, but it does test what it needs to. When you refactor your code in a way that the settings and filesystem are injected, the test will still tell you if the document has those properties set at all.

It's called `unit testing` because you are testing a `unit`, not an object or a method. If your unit has multiple classes, let it be. There's no need everything to be injected and there's no need everything to be mocked - those things ease testing, but in certain cases it's even better not to mock them

Comment: I skip test this method. But probably I will use assertInstanceOf. I don’t have getter for Settings Filesystem, because they shouldn’t be accessible from Document. To check it I will use ReflectionClass.To the second part, I don't know...in my thinking about unit testing (can be wrong), we shouldn't use original implementation of dependencies (and that’s I want to get rid), all should be mocked(stubbed, faked). We testing ‘unit’, but must do it in separately environment, which we can easy configurable. Test this particular 'unit' should pass without matter of anything outside testing ‘unit’.

Comment: @SonnyD I suggest you to read [Test Smell: everything is mocked](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html) by Steve Freeman (or even better - his book Growing object oriented software, guided by tests)

Comment: This is (truly) great advice. I think the question of whether to mock and the question of whether to invert dependencies (e.g. injection) are entirely distinct. I suggest OP evaluates the API to decide if they want to put it behind adapters or not (recommended if the API can be minimized, otherwise using a mock library is probably more appropriate as long as the interface is stable and minimal). I agree that dependencies shouldn't unnecessarily be injected if they're truly value objects with no or very "static" ctor args. In this case OP would want to at least inject the FS ctor parameter.

Comment: Okay, I will try read book you suggest. Example form your link is similar to my problem (Settings class). This answer is most thought-provoking for me. But... finally I just leave this method untested.

Answer (score 3):

[Inject your dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (`Document`, `Settings`, `Filesystem`) via the constructor, then use [test doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) as appropriate.

Also reconsider your 100% coverage policy, it's definitely not clear that it's actually a good thing.

Comment: Okay I get what you mean, this will allow me test method. But I need new instance every time when I create  document.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the dependencies to the factory method, initialize the new object inside, and configure it properly. In the test, the dependencies will be mocks instead of real objects.

**method 1**

Pass factories that allow to create the dependencies:

```
public function getDocument(SettingsFactory $sf, FilesystemFactory $ff){
    $document = new Document();
    $document->settings($sf->getSettings());
    $document->filesystem($ff->getFilesystem());
    return $document;
}
```

In the test, you should:

- create `Settings` instance or mock and a `SettingsFactory` mock that expects one call to `getSettings` and will return the `Settings` instance
- create `Filesystem` instance or mock and a `FilesytemFactory` mock that expects one call to `getFilesystem` and will return the `Filesystem` instance
- call the `DocumentFactory` method, passing the factories. Check that a `Document` object is returned
- check that the objects assigned to `Document` are the same that you configured the mocks to return

A **variant** on this is having the `getSettings` and `getFilesystem` as methods  of the `Document` factory. In that case you should create a partial mock of the Factory, and set the expectations on it. So the real `getDocument` method is called, but when `getSettings` and `getFilesystem` methods are called, you return controlled instances.

**method 2**

Pass the actual dependencies:

```
public function getDocument(Settings $settings, Filesystem $filesystem) {
    $document = new Document();
    $document->settings($settings);
    $document->filesystem($filesystem);
    return $document;
}
```

In the test, you should:

- create `Settings` instance or mock
- create `Filesystem` instance or mock
- call the `DocumentFactory` method, passing the `Settings` and `Filesystem`. Check that a `Document` object is returned
- check that the objects assigned to `Document` are the same instances that you passed to the factory method

Comment: Your idea is good and I understand it. Thanks for writing answer, generally your solution is similar to those form comments I links: (do this again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7763207/2490611 ). I edited my question, please see it.

Comment: Dependency injection can be managed by using some library: https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#dependency-injection

Comment: @SonnyD If you think the answer solved your problem, then you should accept the best answer as a courtesy, but also to help future viewers of this question know what the proper solution was.

Answer (score -2):

Kind of I find answer: this code isn't testable.

> Wherever you have new XXX(...) in a method under test, you are doomed.

More:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7763207/2490611